# Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in Mac OS causes error

Tags: java, macos, runtime

I am trying to use this code in my Java application to run another Jar in Mac OS X :

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd = "java -Xmx1024m -jar \"/Volumes/NANO PRO/My Program/Main.jar\"";
Process process = runtime.exec( cmd );
```

If Main.jar exists in a path with no spaces it will work fine, but since it exists in a path with spaces, it causes the error :

[image]

**Is there a way to make this run in a path that has spaces ?**

Comment: It seems stripping file name because of space. Error message not showing entire path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an array to build different parts of your command and leave it to Java runtime to convert them appropriately based on the underlying environment.

```
String [] cmd = {"java", 
                 "-Xmx1024m", 
                 "-jar",
                 "/Volumes/NANO PRO/My Program/Main.jar"};
```

Also you can take a look at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

Comment: Thanks .. That works. I have already read about the array parameter, but i didn't understand that every part of the command should be as a separate element in the array.